# $transition$ not working when injected in a controller / ui-router 1.0.0-beta.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

in the official doc :

https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/modules/ng1.html , in the example :

```
MyController.$inject = ['$transition$'];
function MyController($transition$) {
    var username = $transition$.params().username;
    // .. do something with username
}
```

$transition$ is injected in the controller, but when I do the same with angular 1.6.1 and ui-router 1.0.0-beta.3 I have the follwing error, using a component architecture:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $transition$Provider

I am able to inject $transition$ only in a resolve.

Answer (score 1):

From the ui-router [Route to Component](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#accessing-transition) guide:

> When routing to a **legacy style template/controller** (not routing to
>   components), the transition could be injected as $transition$.
>
> ...
>
> To access the Transition on a routed **component**, you should bind to
>   $transition$ in your component.

As you noted, therefore this can only be accessed via the resolve when routing to components. This is because the `$transition$` service is a locally scoped injectable which is not available for components. More information can be found in issue [ui-router#3110](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3110)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject the '$transition$' object where you should be injecting the '$transitions' service into your controller. See the distinction in the documentation on this page:

[https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#*transition*](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/injectables.html#_transition_)

Comment: thanx for the help, but the problem was discussed here : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3244

Answer (score 0):

`$transition$` isn't a global `service`, it's a locally scoped `injectable`.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3110

You can use component input bindings to address this:

```
.component('adminApplicants',{
    bindings: { $transition$: '<' },
    templateUrl:'admin.applicants.html',
    controller:function($http,$transition$){
    }
})
```